# How to do an array merge between two functions?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get an `array_merge` but I can't. Calling the example.php file must also embed the array of the `Usage_Module` function.

**Note:** The `getFunctionModule` function must not be changed.

Surely I'm wrong something in the `Usage_Module` function, can you help me understand what I'm wrong?

**Code example.php**

```
function getFunctionModule() {

require "module.php";
$func = "Usage_Module";
            if (!function_exists($func)) {
                        echo "function not found";
            }
return (array) $func();
}

$data = ['status' => 'ok'];
$data = array_merge(getFunctionModule(), $data);
print_r($data);
```

**Code module.php**

```
function Usage_Module()
    {
        $data = ['licensekey2' => 'ok'];
        return (array) $data;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It doesn't merge the two arrays, it shows them separate `Array ( [licensekey2] => ok ) Array ( [status] => ok )`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The two arrays are merged when I try your code. You are also unnecessarily casting to array in two places. You're already returning an array.

Comment: @Albert Cannot reproduce the issue. See this link https://3v4l.org/80tC0